# Drop-down-menu works great with Firefox, but not with WebKit

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am working on a Drop-Down-Menu only using CSS & HTML5 (no JavaScript) in my personal website. Here it is: http://davidvalles.cu.cc

If you enter with Firefox, the menu works great (it is the one called "Secciones"): when you put the mouse over the "Secciones" div, the menu appears with a transition.

But if you try it with Safari or Chrome, it will work normally, unless you put the mouse UNDER the "Secciones" div. In that case, menu will appear normally. And I don't want the menu to open in that case. I only want it to open when you put the mouse over the "Secciones" link (all the box that contains the Secciones text).

What am I doing wrong? Why does the menu work perfectly in Firefox but not in Safari?
Could you take a look at it? Thank you, and sorry for my poor English, I'm learning. Please, correct me :)

Answer (score 0):

Your easing? Is "ease" a easing value?

```
-moz-transition: opacity .25s ease;
-webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease;
-o-transition: opacity .25s ease;
-ms-transition: opacity .25s ease;
transition: opacity .25s ease;
```

Comment: I solved it. It was a problem with the code which was previous to the menu. A div was higher than that he had to be.

By the way, according to w3schools.com ( http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-timing-function.asp ), ease is a valid value to easing property.

Thanks!